# How to use pg_dump correctly in order to do a database migration?

Tags: sql, postgresql, macos, terminal, database-migration

Hey everyone I am fairly new to doing a pg_dump in Postgre sql. I have logged into the server and am running as postgres user. I try to run the pg_dump in order to do a database migration but I keep getting a "Permission Denied" prompt. I believe that I have the highest permissions and should be able to run this. Is there something wrong with my syntax in terminal? Would appreciate the help.

Issue:

*

```
[user@dfhsdaf07 ~]$ sudo su
[root@dfhsdaf07 user]# su postgres
bash-4.2$ pg_dump -F t file > file.tar
bash: file.tar: Permission denied
bash-4.2$ pg_dump -F t file >./file.tar
bash: ./file.tar: Permission denied
```

- 

System info:

Macbook Pro 2015

16 GB RAM

Intel I7 Processoor

OS:

macOS Big Sur 11.5.2

Comment: Do not use an image to show textual information. Copy and paste the text as update to your question. The permissions issue is with creating the the file. Looks like you are trying as `postgres` user to create file in `root` user directory. All the `sudo\su`  commands are not needed . Do this in your home directory and just add `-U postgres` to the `pg_dump` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adrian. I will take your advice and only copy and paste from now on. I will try this and mark this question as solved afterwards.

Comment: This worked!  Thanks alot Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission you are lacking is the permission to create the dump file in the current directory.

The reason is that if you use `so postgres`, you remain in the previous working directory (presumably `/root`), and user `postgres` doesn't have permissions to create a file there.

Use the `-` option:

```sh
su - postgres`
```

That will start a login shell and put you into `postgres`'s home directory.

Comment: Or just do `cd` after `su postgres`